# Javascript Function Events Not Firing in Order

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is meant to clear a div of all its children with a specific name before refilling said div with a new set of children.

```
function displaySearchResults(resultsList) {
var length = resultsList.length;
var searchDiv = document.getElementById('search-results');

//CLEAR DIV
if(searchDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
    for(var i=0; i<searchDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var oldChild = searchDiv.childNodes[i];
        if(oldChild.id.indexOf('search-results-row') != -1) {
            searchDiv.removeChild(oldChild);
            console.log('Removed Result!');
        }
    }
}

//ADD CHILDREN  
for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    console.log('Added Result!');
    var element = resultsList[i];
    var rowDiv = document.createElement('div');
    rowDiv.id = 'search-results-row' + i;
    rowDiv.className = 'list listRow' + i%2;
    rowDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'mapCurrentContact(' + i + ');');
    rowDiv.innerHTML = element.firstName + ' ' + element.lastName;
    searchDiv.appendChild(rowDiv);
}
}
```

However it starts running the ADD CHILDREN portion of the function before the CLEAR DIV loop has a chance to finish. So for instance, if the function finds 4 childNodes in the div and begins looping through to remove each one with the id of search-results-row, it will only get through 2 or so before it begins appending the new set of results that was initially passed into the function.

I know that Javascript runs asynchronously, but I thought that functions themselves at least run top down so the bottom portion should not do anything until we reach that part of the code? I have tried all sorts of other alternatives such as running the CLEAR DIV portion in its own function and then calling the ADD CHILDREN portion at the end, but I always get the same results. What am I missing here!?!

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but in the clear div block, consider looping down, not up. When a childNode is removed, the searchDiv.childNode variable changes in length.

Comment: What do you mean by "I know JavaScript runs asynchronously"? Also, just take note that the variable `i` only exists once in that function, not once for each `for` loop: that's not related, but it does throw people off. You're skipping over child nodes, as Jeffrey notes.

Comment: I think I need a little clarification. I'm missing how i'm skipping over nodes and how the i does not change as the loop progresses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove items from the beginning of a list:

```
V
a b c d //Initial list with the counter being 0, pointing to 'a'

V
b c d   //Removed the element 'a'

  V
b c d   //Incremented the counter by one
```

You end up skipping over element `b` and repeating the same error for every other element in the list.  You can either decrement the counter when you remove something or simply start from the end of the list, in which case you will only affect the index of elements you have already looked at.  The latter is more widely accepted.

```
var i; //JavaScript does not have block scope, only function scope.  Just declare it once here and initialize it at the beginning of each loop.
for(i=searchDiv.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i++) {
```

Comment: I didn't realize that the for loop changed after being initially called. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't change the code in your original question.  If someone has a similar problem in the future, they can see your original code and look at the accepted answer for how to fix it.

Comment: @ryandlf The `for` loop doesn't change, you're using an index to access items in a shrinking collection.

Answer (score 0):

When removing remove from the end instead:

```
for(var i=searchDiv.childNodes.length; i>=0; i--) {
...
```

You current for loop will fail. Also javascript it self is not asynchronous. An asynchronous call could be like below:

```
// this will be called first
$.ajax({
  url: 'getsomedata.php',
  success: function() {
    // this will not be called until the getsomedata.php has completed
    // and the for loop below might already be finished.
  }
});

// this directly after the ajax call
for (var i=0; i<10; i00) {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I refactored your code a bit:

```
function displaySearchResults( results ) {
    var elem = document.getElementById( 'search-results' );

    [].slice.call( elem.children ).forEach( function ( child ) {
        if ( child.id.indexOf( 'search-results-row' ) > -1 ) {
            elem.removeChild( child );
        }
    });

    results.forEach( function ( result, i ) {
        var child = document.createElement( 'div' );
        child.id = 'search-results-row' + i;
        child.className = 'list listRow' + ( i % 2 );
        child.onclick = function () { mapCurrentContact( i ); };
        child.textContent = result.firstName + ' ' + result.lastName;       
        elem.appendChild( child );
    });
}
```

Also, I recommend event delegation for the click behavior. Just bind a click handler on the `search-results` DIV, and use the event object to determine which child element was clicked.

Btw, there are CSS selectors to match even / odd child elements. For instance:

```
#search-results > :nth-child(even) { ... }
#search-results > :nth-child(odd) { ... }
```

So, you don't need that `listRow0` and `listRow1` classes, really.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ez4z3/